# Stored procedure for Insert won't execute and throws 2 errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure and it looks to be set up properly, here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Insert$Order$For$Travel
(
@CardHolderName varchar(50),--Userprofile
@CardNumber int, --Userprofile
@SecurityCode int, --Userprofile
@ExpiryDate date, --Userprofile
@DeparturePoint int, --Order
@DestinationPoint int, --Order
@DepartureTime datetime, --Order
@DestinationTime datetime, --Order
@Passengers int, --Order
@RoundTrip char(3), --Order
@ReturnDate datetime, --Order
@OrderNumber int --order
)
AS
Declare @UserIdentity int

Insert into [UserProfile]
(CardHolderName, CardHolderName, SecurityCode, ExpiryDate)
values
(@CardHolderName, @CardNumber, @SecurityCode, @ExpiryDate)
set @UserIdentity = @@IDENTITY

Insert into [Order]
(DeparturePoint, DestinationPoint, DepartureTime, DestinationPoint,DestinationTime,Passengers,RoundTrip, ReturnDate, OrderNumber, UserID)
values
(@DeparturePoint, @DestinationPoint, @DepartureTime, @DestinationPoint, @DestinationTime,@Passengers, @RoundTrip, @ReturnDate, @OrderNumber, @UserIdentity)
```

when I go to execute it I am receiving these 2 errors.

> Msg 264, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Insert$Order$For$Travel, Line 25
>   The column name 'CardHolderName' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once.  If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.
>
> Msg 264, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Insert$Order$For$Travel, Line 31
>   The column name 'DestinationPoint' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once.  If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.

I have looked over my stored procedure and look at others that I have done in the past and it looks to be ok, I just don't see where the issue is.

Anyone see what the issue is that I am having? I have checked my parameters and they are all correct based on the columns in the tables that I want to insert them in...

Any ideas?

Comment: @fabulaspb, noticed it and pointed it out to me.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks for the tip. All this time I have always used the prefix of sp_ and never thought anything of it. I'm going to keep that in mind for all my future stored procedures

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what the error says:

```
 Insert into [UserProfile]
 (CardHolderName, CardHolderName, SecurityCode, ExpiryDate)
 values
 (@CardHolderName, @CardNumber, @SecurityCode, @ExpiryDate)
```

... has CardHolderName *twice* in the destination columns.  Presumably the second one should be `CardNumber`.

The other is similar.

Comment: Yea, it was an error on my part, I didn't realize that I had duplicated the columns in my sp. I removed both duplicates and its working now. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Insert into [UserProfile](CardHolderName, CardNumber, SecurityCode, ExpiryDate)
    values (@CardHolderName, @CardNumber, @SecurityCode, @ExpiryDate);

set @UserIdentity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

I think you want `CardNumber` for the second variable rather than `CardHolderName`.

I also changed the `@@IDENTITY` to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, which is safer.

EDIT:

I think the documentation does a good job of explaining it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

The basic idea is that the four ways of getting the most recent identity (`@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTIY()`, `IDENT_CURRENT()`, and the `OUTPUT` clause).  The safest is the `OUTPUT` clause.  The other three depend on three things:  the "table",  the "connection", and the "scope".

The first two return the most recent identity *regardless* of table, but on the same connection.  If there is an insert trigger on the table, the trigger might insert a value into another table.  `@@IDENTITY` will return the `id` from that table (same connection, different scope).  `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will return the `id` from the intended table (same connection, same scope).  `IDENT_CURRENT()` is just inviting a race condition with other connections that might also be adding rows onto the table.

The `OUTPUT` clause doesn't suffer from these  interpretations.  It just puts the values from the `insert` into a temporary table -- at the expense of a bit more coding and learning something new.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain the difference between @@Identity and Scope_Identity, I have always used @@identity and this Scope_Identity is new to me

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and links. Now I have a better understanding of the differences

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in the following lines:

```
Insert into [UserProfile]
(CardHolderName, CardHolderName, SecurityCode, ExpiryDate)
```

Repeated column name "CardHolderName" twice in insert statement to table "UserProfile"

```
Insert into [Order]
(DeparturePoint, DestinationPoint, DepartureTime, DestinationPoint)
```

Repeated column name "DestinationPoint" twice in insert statement to table "Order".

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't even notice that